# Django RSS add attribute into item

Tags: python, django, rss

Just a quick question that I have been having trouble with all day. Hopefully my google skills just havent failed me ;)

I want to add an extra field to the `<item>`, something like:

```
<item>
    <title></title>
    <myfield></myfield>
</item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I dont like answering my own questions, I figured out how and its rather simple...once its demonstrated. Credit does not go to me, but I found [this link](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/01/how-to-create-a-custom-feed-in-django-using-the-syndication-feed-framework/comment-page-1/#comment-4989)

```
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Rss201rev2Feed
class CustomFeedGenerator(Rss201rev2Feed):
    def add_item_elements(self, handler, item):
        super(CustomFeedGenerator, self).add_item_elements(handler, item)
        handler.addQuickElement(u"featured", item['featured'])
```

then add the following within your feed class definition

```
def item_extra_kwargs(self, obj):
    return { 'featured': val}
```

Of course, `featured` was the field I wanted to add... Thanks to the people at the link I posted above!

Comment: thanks for this. was working on a legacy django 1.2 project and this was a life saver :)

Comment: @neolaser what am I missing? `val` is not defined in `item_extra_kwargs`.